# What is the difference between prefixes of WebGL extensions

Tags: webgl, opengl-es-2.0

What is the difference between prefixes of WebGL extensions?

There is several prefixes for WebGL extensions like `ANGLE` , `OES` , `WEBGL` or `EXT`. What is actual difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/).

> WebGL API extensions may derive from many sources, and the naming of
>   each extension reflects its origin and intent.

More about each tags:

- ANGLE tag should be used if [Angle](https://github.com/google/angle) library is used.
- OES tag should be used for mirroring functionality from OpenGL ES or
  OpenGL API extensions approved by the respective architecture review 
  boards.
- EXT tag should be used or mirroring other OpenGL ES or OpenGL API
  extensions. If only small differences in behavior compared to OpenGL
  ES or OpenGL are specified for a given extension, the original tag 
  should be maintained.
- WEBGL tag should be used for WebGL-specific extensions which are 
  intended to be compatible with multiple web browsers. It should also 
  be used for extensions which originated with the OpenGL ES or OpenGL
  APIs, but whose behavior has been significantly altered.

Comment: Thank you for answering for this question!Your answer is clearly the answer.